# detect npm run dev or npm build at runtime

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next and I want to display a `<Component>` only when `npm run dev` was invoked, for debugging purposes and not display it when it was `npm build`. Is there anything that Next/React declare for this? Kind of `ifdef DEBUG` if you used to `C` as I am.

Comment: Did you try this `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` with condition statement. @exebook

Comment: @DSDmark that was my first thought but isn't `process` server side only?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The process object is only available on the server-side in a Next.js app.

Comment: `__NEXT_DATA__.env` object, which is provided by Next.js and is available on the client-side. Like this `__NEXT_DATA__.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`

Comment: `process.env` cannot be accessed on the client-side. in nextjs @exebook

Comment: @DSDmark cool, didn't know about `__NEXT_DATA__`, but you can't just use it, you still need to to wrap it inside `useEffect()`

Comment: Yup, the `useEffect` hook is being used to perform a side effect when the component mounts.  Side effect is to access that object I mean `__NEXT_DATA__`

Comment: You can use `getInitialProps` method. if you don't want `useEffect()`

Comment: Note for posterity, you can also provide `process.env` to the client by [extending the Webpack config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) and using [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), like: `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ isDev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' })`

Comment: In addition to your comment, Mr.@Zac Anger, `DefinePlugin` are inlined into the code at build time, so they cannot be changed at runtime. This means that you should only use the `DefinePlugin` for values that are known at build time.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to check if `window.location.hostname == "localhost"` but this can only be done inside `useEffect` or you will get random error messages.

```
function Debug({ children }) {
    const [debug, setDebug] = useState(undefined)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.hostname == 'localhost') setDebug(true)
    })
    return : debug ? <span>children</span> : null
}
```